# Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when loading jobs on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to setup a CI environment using Jenkins for my Maven project.
I configured it and it compiles, but when Jenkins is restarted, the job is not shown in the GUI. Taking a look at the log, I get:

> SEVERE: Failed Loading job test java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space
>           at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
>           at java.util.Vector.grow(Vector.java:262)
>           at java.util.Vector.ensureCapacityHelper(Vector.java:242)
>           at java.util.Vector.addElement(Vector.java:616)
>           at java.util.Stack.push(Stack.java:67)
>           at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.onLoad(MavenModuleSet.java:810)
>           at hudson.model.Items.load(Items.java:279)
>           at jenkins.model.Jenkins$18.run(Jenkins.java:2634)
>           at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
>           at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
>           at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:885)
>           at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
>           at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am trying to troubleshoot it and I noticed that it only happens after I run a build (if I configure it and restart Jenkins, it shows up. If I run a Build and restart again, it disappears)

I searched for this problem and I got many answers

1- going to Manage > Configuration > Maven Project Config and adding -Xmx1048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m to Maven_opts

2- Adding JAVA_OPTS in Manage > Configuration > Environment Variables

3- Going to /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and changing JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS

4- I shuold be able to change jenkins_home/jenkins.xml, but it doesn't exist

How can I solve this?

Thanks

I've added this line:

```
 -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

To my /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file and using jps -mlv I can check that it is being applied.
Even though, the issue stills happens.
It happens when loading the job, not running it, so I think that Maven's heap is not the problem here...

Comment: The stacktrace also reveals that it is Jenkins that runs out of heap space, so definitely not Maven related. BTW, you have duplicated memory options. I would probably see if I can switch jenkins into debugmode and apply a remote debugger with a breakpoint on OOM. Alternatively use the java mission control (from jdk7v45 onwards) to attach to the process and get it to dump heap on oom. Let me know if you need any pointers for this.

Comment: I will try to do it and get back to this question if I have issues. Thanks :)